# How to collect custom metrics from Spark based application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, metrics, instrumentation

I have a `Spark` (java) based application which scans few tables in `Hive` and then based on some condition, it gives a list of table/partitions which satisfy the condition.

I want to know how I can collect information regarding this scan?

For eg: How much time it took the application to perform the scan of different tables? How much memory was being used while performing the scan? etc.
I know i can use simple stopwatch for time calculation and print them to the log. But i do not want them to print into logs. I want to push the to a custom `Kafka producer` that i have created.

1. I looked into using spark listener and extending them: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener
   But these are based on spark specific events(onJobStart, onJobEnd, etc.). I want to trigger my listener on business specific events. For eg: onTableRead, onSpecificMethodCall

2)https://github.com/groupon/spark-metrics
I had a look at this library and it is quite simple to use. But the problem here I am facing is that my Spark application is java based.
In the spark-metrics documentation, they have mentioned the metrics should be initialized as lazy vals to get correct data.

```
public List getFilteredPartList(){
List<String> fileteredPartitions = utils.getPartNames(getTable().getDbName(), getTable().getTableName(),getConfiguration().getEnvCode(), partNames,
getTableProperties(), getDataAccessManager(), true, true, false, true).getPartNames()};
```

I want to know the time taken for the execution of above method and push it to my custom Kafka producer.

Comment: Use spark listener to collect your custom.metrics read hps by Holden  karau in that it was mentioned

Comment: First approach stopwatch is right why you need to print you can create small json and publish in to kafka message

Comment: Drop spark listener idea

Comment: Json can be published instead of print ... Print also can be done along but not required

Comment: Sure i will try the stopwatch idea. Thanks @Ram

Comment: Can you show how you do _"which scans few tables in Hive"_?

Comment: It's a simple check. I have a shell script in which i pass the schema name and table name as arguments. It will check that table for a certain condition (for eg: all the partitions created after a certain date) and make a list of those partitions. As shown above(again pasting below):
`public List getFilteredPartList(){
List<String> fileteredPartitions = utils.getPartNames(getTable().getDbName(), getTable().getTableName(),getConfiguration().getEnvCode(), partNames,
getTableProperties(), getDataAccessManager(), true, true, false, true).getPartNames()};`